# How can I make xchat split long lines across multiple lines?

Tags: irc, xchat

I am using xchat as my IRC client on Ubuntu 9.10. It's mostly fine, but when I get a message that's wider than the screen, I can't view the end of it as it goes off the edge of the screen. How do I make xchat split long lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature you are missing is called word-wrapping, and it works on my updated karmic. Apparently there is no option on the graphical interface to turn this on/off.

Take a look at the line beginning with *text_wordwrap* on the file */home/your username/.xchat2/xchat.conf*

It should be set to 1. That line should be:

```
text_wordwrap = 1
```

If it's set to 0, you can use a text editor to change that value to 1.

EDIT: see comments

Comment: It is set to 1. However, it does not split the lines.

Comment: You can try renaming the directory ~/.xchat to create a new configuration the next time xchat is started, and check if the problem remains.

Comment: That fixed it. I just reset all my customisations and it works now.

Comment: That as in the comment btw.